# CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have to "translate" a MySQL SQL script (table and index creations basically) to PostgreSQL and have come across the following:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX param_description   ON info_param (description ASC) ;
```

Where *description* is a **TEXT** column.

Is there a straightforward way to directly translate the above into some indexing command in PostgreSQL 9.1 ?

Comment: [Chapter 12. Full Text Search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html).

The full text search model in PostgreSQL is different in more than details of syntax. You will need to use different functions and operators to query the index. You cannot just run code written for MySQL's fulltext indexes against PostgreSQL's fulltext indexing.

Comment: Right, I was hoping for a more or less straightforward syntax-only translation.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus You're out of luck, unfortunately. `to_tsvector('english','some text here') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'te:*')` isn't super similar to what MySQL uses ;-)